# CTFrame dropping glyphs at the edge

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-text, truetype

I am trying to render Arabic text in my iOS app with custom TTF font (scheherazade) using core-text, which works for the most part - however certain glyphs at the edge of the CTFrame are dropped.

When I adjust the frame-size to make the dropped-glyphs appear in the interior of the frame, they display corretly, which leads me believe something is going wrong in inside CTFrameDraw. Below is the code I'm using to render the Arabic-text:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Flip the coordinate system
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, v.textFrame.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); //1
 CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, v.textFrame );

CGFloat minLineHeight = 60.0;
CGFloat maxLineHeight = 60.0;

CTTextAlignment paragraphAlignment = kCTRightTextAlignment;
CTLineBreakMode lineBrkMode = kCTLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CTParagraphStyleSetting setting[4] = {
{kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &paragraphAlignment},
{kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &minLineHeight},
{kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &maxLineHeight},
{kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode, sizeof(CTLineBreakMode), &lineBrkMode}
};


CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(setting, 4);
NSDictionary *attr        = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
(id)v.arabicFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
paragraphStyle, (id)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
nil];

CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

NSAttributedString* attString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
initWithString:v.verseText attributes:attr] autorelease]; //2

CTFramesetterRef framesetter =
CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attString); //3
CTFrameRef frame =
CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,
CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(frame, context); //4

CFRelease(frame); //5
CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(framesetter);
```

Also attached are the screenshots showing the problem I face. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

invalid: http://stellarbeacon.com.au/invalid.png
valid  : http://stellarbeacon.com.au/valid.png

Comment: I have the same problem with other fonts. Take a look here if you've already found an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755757/ctframedraw-cut-some-fonts

Comment: @Coolant: Thankfully just yesterday I figured the problem goes away with a slightly different font, which I'm not sure would apply to your case. Please read comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some bugs in CoreText related to determining the correct frame size. Some of these where fixed in iOS 6, e.g. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/radar-coretext-line-spacing-bug/

If your problem still exists there then you should file a Radar with the specifics. Also you should open a call with Apple DTS which can probably provide you with a workaround. Often - if your problem is indeed a bug - then you get your DTS call credited back.

PS: try to display your text with my DTCoreText views which do manual layouting and display and see if the problem can be reproduced there. If not then you have your workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried so many things over the last few weeks, I've almost lost track - but I've definitely tried manual laying out, with the problem still persisting.

However, luckily just yesterday I figured with a slightly different font the problem goes away, which makes perfect sense after reading your post...:)

Comment: Yeah, I tested in iOS6 and the problem is still there.

Comment: The Apple engineer who confirmed to me the iOS 6 fixes mentioned that for some fonts the embedded metrics where missing or wrong. So using different fonts can also be a workaround. But definitely file a Radar so that they'll fix this issue in the future.